# In repeat grid we can not give a different label to Text Output conrtols on each row

Tags: orbeon

In Orbeon Forms M16 (latest) build in repeat grid we can not give a different label to Text Output conrtols on each row. It's not practical. In previous milestone version it was possible. That's why we can't make a simple table with header in first column and first row like in MS Excel. Is there a workaround - some other way to make a simple table with headers in the first column and in the first row?

Comment: Seems like you're asking several questions here. Can you focus on one of them?

Comment: OK... but if I understand the question you're focusing on, it seems to be a question that only Orbeon Inc. can answer: why did they omit a particular feature? That's not a question for StackOverflow. A question for StackOverflow would be, e.g. Is there a workaround - some other way to make a simple table with headers in the first column and in the first row?

Comment: @LarsH, you're right. Thank you. I have made the updates.

Comment: I think this is now a valuable question. I have upvoted it and also voted for it to be reopened. I'm glad you found a workaround. This should be helpful for others who are facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved.
We have to do:
1) Maximum Number of Repetitions: 1
2) Push "Insert Row Below instead of "+" button